# jQuery ui replace contents of dragged item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to replace the dropped item's html content. I'm able to append the new html content but in this case the `sortable` receives the dragged item as well as appends the new item.

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).append('<li class="new">this is item 1</li>');
```

How can I actually replace the dragged item with the new item instead of appending? Or remove the original dragged item?

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/v97u5qtx/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="answers">
  <li id="item-1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="item-2">Item 2</li>

</ul>

<ul class="container">
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    $("#answers li").draggable({
      connectToSortable: '.container',
      helper: 'clone',
      revertDuration: 0,
    revert: true
    });

    $(".container").sortable({
        connectWith: '.container',
            revert: true,
        receive: function (event, ui) {
          var id = ui.item.attr("id");

             if ( id == 'item-1') {
            $(this).append('<li class="new">this is item 1</li>');    
          } else if ( id == 'item-2') {
            $(this).append('<li class="new">this is item 2</li>'); 
          }    
        }
    });

    $("ul, li").disableSelection();

});
```

Comment: Is it ok for you? http://jsfiddle.net/7szcwv6p/

Comment: @HardikLeuwa Thanks but as you in your example when you drag a second item, it removes all previously dragged items, so that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this,

Updated container code as following,

```
$(".container").sortable({
    connectWith: '.container',
        revert: true,
    receive: function (event, ui) {
      var id = ui.item.attr("id");

      if ( id == 'item-1') {
        $(this).append('<li class="new">this is item 1</li>');    
      } else if ( id == 'item-2') {
        $(this).append('<li class="new">this is item 2</li>'); 
      }    

      $('.container .ui-draggable').remove();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7szcwv6p/1/)**